# Three.js Loading .mtl and .obj - object stays white

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj

I want to load an object with different textures on different places - so I looked at the examples provided by three.js at https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html. The object is getting loaded but it has no different textures on it.

This is the code I typed:

```
   // LOAD TREE Example
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath("Assets/Objects/Tree_V9_OBJ/");
    mtlLoader.load("Tree_V9_Final.mtl", function(materials){
        materials.preload();
        console.log(materials);
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath('Assets/Objects/Tree_V9_OBJ/');
        objLoader.load('Tree_V9_Final.obj', function(object){
            console.log(object);
            object.scale.x = 10;
            object.scale.y = 10;
            object.scale.z = 10;
            scene.add(object);
        });
    });
```

My folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

The result:

[image: The Result]

The console output

[image: Console output]

The Source of the object:

http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/tree-for-modification-v9-16618.html

I'm new to three.js so I don't know where I have to search for the bug.

**There is no error thrown in the console.**

How can I fix this so the object is getting loaded correctly with the textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The model is broken (textures are not referenced in the `.mtl` = material file.)

Just add the texture paths into `Tree_V9_Final.mtl` :

```
# Blender MTL File: 'Tree_V9_Final.blend'
# Material Count: 4

newmtl bark_tree
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd bark_tree.jpg

newmtl leaves_01
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd leaves_01.jpg

newmtl leaves_02
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd leaves_02.jpg

newmtl leaves_03
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd leaves_03.jpg
```

**Note**

Your model also provide normal maps and alpha maps for the leaves. I suggest you read the [.mtl specification](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/) so you can add those inside the `.mtl` file.

Comment: awesome it's working - never would have found that issue